# Location Provider SAMSUNG always returns true

Tags: android, location, locationmanager, samsung-mobile

I am trying to check if it is possible to fetch the location using Location Manager using the below procedure

LocationManager service = (LocationManager).getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
boolean network = service.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

The above logic works fine in Sony Ericsson, but when it comes to samsung, 
'service.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)' always returns true.,
even with GPS , WiFi turned OFF and even with out a SIM card inserted.

Did anybody come across this?
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what model of samsung phone are you testing on?

Comment: is it throwing any exceptions?  What happens when you call getAllProviders()?

Comment: No exceptions., I have not called getAllProviders()., but I when I did to check, the log shows this '[network, passive, gps]'

Comment: It sounds to be like a hardware bug.  I did a quick search but didn't see any reports about that issue.

Comment: Same problem here, Samsung GT-P5100.