# `locationManager.isProviderEnabled(locationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);` always returns true

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, location, locationmanager

I am testing an app which uses `Location` services. And it returns null causing `NPE (Null Pointer Exception)` whenever my Location Services are turned off. So after some searching I found that

```
    isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(locationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

should return the correct `boolean value` but when testing my app it seems to always return `true` causing a `NPE (Null Pointer Exception)` and crashing my app.

I also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11437327/android-locationmanager-isproviderenabled-always-returns-false) question. Which has the exact opposite problem apparently and tried that solution. That also didn't work. I am testing on a Samsung G5. Why is this happening. Is something wrong in the code or is there another solution to my problem.

Here is the code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    isGPSEnabled = false;
    intentThatCalled = getIntent();
    String m2txt = intentThatCalled.getStringExtra("v2txt");
    getLocation(m2txt);
}
public void getLocation(String n2txt) {
    locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    criteria = new Criteria();
    bestProvider = String.valueOf(locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true)).toString();
    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
    isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(locationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if (isGPSEnabled==true) {
        Log.e("TAG", "GPS is on");
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
        Toast.makeText(PlacesDecoder.this, "latitude:" + latitude + " longitude:" + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        searchNearestPlace(n2txt);
    }
}
```

I am still a beginner in android.
Please do help.

**EDIT:**
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10583058/location-provider-samsung-always-returns-true?rq=1) question seems to have the same problem on the same Hardware model. Is this a Hardware Bug? If it is, is there any other possibility. I will also test on another device Note-4 and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to your problem is to **NEVER** assume you have a location, Just because your GPS is enabled does not mean you will get a location.

At any time you can get a `null` location so instead of worrying about if the GPS is enabled or not you should worry about if your location returned is null or not.

`getLastKnownLocation()` can return a null if there is no last location

Comment: I tried this but when I do that it asks for permission `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` which when added messes up my app.

Comment: Is there any other way?

Comment: tried do you what, check for a null? if you want to get data from gps you need to have the permission `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`

Comment: Yes thanks I tried it now and it worked. Before it crashed. I don't know why. But thanks anyway. It's working now.

Comment: Sorry but this always returns false.

Comment: Sorry it was a an accident

Comment: there is no reason to do what you are trying to do, if you dont want to listen to how I told you to fix it then I cannot help

Comment: No I did what you told. But it displayed an error for permission ACCESS FINE LOCATION. And if I do that location always returns null.